# Edit Text won't inflate in the action bar

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate an EditText into the action bar using the following code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main , menu);
       !! MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(R.id.item2);
                !!EditText et = (EditText) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mi).findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                et.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Notes: Statements marked with !! are causing the application to crash.
I am using minSdk 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast the `MenuItem` with its class (`(MenuItem)`), use `findItem` method and use an inflated `View` to retrieve the `EditText` as follows:

```
// cast the menu item
MenuItem mi = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.item2);
// Use an inflated view
View view = (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mi);
// Retrieve the edittext
EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

In the short way, as your code, it might be resumed by this following code:

```
MenuItem mi = (MenuItem) menu.getItem(R.id.item2);
EditText et = (EditText) ( (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mi) ).findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Make sure you return `true` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` instead of `super` method.
Finally, make also sure the item uses a custom prefix like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:customapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        customapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        customapp:actionLayout="@layout/layout_edittext" ... />
</menu>
```

Comment: I tried both of your ways to do it. But it still crashes just like before with the same error in LogCat.

Comment: Maybe @Saad you forgot the custom prefix into the menu item. See my updated answer. If this isn't working, it might be useful to post the logcat into your question.

Comment: It worked man. I wasn't adding the custom prefix with actionLayout. God!!! everything everyday changes in android.

Comment: You're welcome ;) And it's not changing everyday.. I mean.. almost. However, this behaviour is mentioned in [the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) (the 3rd snippet code and specially the **Using XML attributes from the support library** part).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add android support v7 appcompat library project to your Project.
2. Update value for attribute theme as  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" in your activity's entry in manifest file.
3. Create a layout resource for your custom action bar as

   custom_action_bar.xml

   ```
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/test_edit"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Please enter text here !"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:inputType="text" />
   ```
4. Your activity will now be extending ActionBarActivity instead of Activity.
5. In onCreate() of your activity after super() call, add the following code lines  :

   View actionBarLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);

   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

   ```
   actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

   actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);




       EditText editText = (EditText) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.test_edit);
       editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
       {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
           {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Log.e("TAG", "key action");
               return false;
           }
       });
   ```

Alternative, instead you can try adding action views http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Comment: What if you simply add listeners to your views in your custom action bar layout and use them and forget about your onCreateOptionsMenu. 
I am just asking will not that work the way you want. You just want views to be added in the actionbar and then start interacting to it.

Comment: It just bugs you know when you can't do a thing in a way that can be done. But hey thanks it was helpful. And I did solve my  problem