# Edit Text won't inflate in menu

Tags: java, android, android-menu

My hair turned white from this, so I'm hoping you guys can shed some light.

So, the problem is that EditText does not get inflated into the menu, though other items, both before and after, are properly inflated.

The java code:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_notes_optionsmenu, menu);
            title_textbox = (EditText)menu.findItem(R.id.title_textbox);
            return true;
        }
```

title_textbox remains null. With the step by step debugger, I saw that after inflation, the menu has the following items:

https://gyazo.com/8a76c0bd702568f4c46a8ef2af1a03c5 (Image linked as I do not have 10 rep to embed it.)

Between back and accept, there should be the edittext as defined in activity_main_notes_optionsmenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menubar">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back_button"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Back"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title_textbox"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/accept"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Accept"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="none" android:orderInCategory="4">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/renamenote"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Rename Note" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/deletenote"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Delete Note" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The only functional workaround I could find, was to add the EditText inside the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead, however in that case the orderInCategory is ignored, and the Edittext will always be the left most item, followed by the items in the menu. The desired behaviour is that from left to right, we have back button, EditText, Accept button, then the final 2 in a overflow window.

Other questions that touched on this subject are:

[Add EditText to Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980561/add-edittext-to-toolbar) - usable workaround as described above, but it's not a proper solution because of the limitation of positioning.

[menu.findItem(R.id.*) is null- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902946/menu-finditemr-id-is-null-android) - Was a simple case of trying to use the object before inflating, not my case.

[Android : Display an EditText in a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699073/android-display-an-edittext-in-a-menu) - Seems to say it's not possible? Though according to many other sources, it is possible.

[Edit Text won't inflate in the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558690/edit-text-wont-inflate-in-the-action-bar) - Looks like identical problem to mine, however In the accepted answer the first part is about casting, but my problem is that it's not there in the first place, and the part about custom prefix I tried, but does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, the problem is that EditText does not get inflated into the menu, though other items, both before and after, are properly inflated.

Since that has never been valid, this is not surprising.

> The only functional workaround I could find, was to add the EditText inside the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead

I am somewhat surprised that this worked as well as you say that it did. I would have expected `Toolbar` to ignore random non-menu XML elements as well.

You are welcome to use [an `ActionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ActionProvider.html) or [an action view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(android.view.View)).